# Create a function for Least Common Multiple for a vector in R with helper functions

Tags: r, loops, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

In R,
I have two helper functions

gcf(x,y) for finding the greatest common factor of two numbers

and

lcm(x,y) for finding the lease common multple of two numbers.

For example,

```
> gcd(85,75)
[1] 5
> lcm(20,50)
[1] 100
```

Now, I need to create a function that takes a vector of integers as the argument that returns the least common multiple for the elements.

for example,

```
lcm_vector(c(20,50,75)) = 300
```

I know that this will take calculation

LCM(20, 50, 75) = LCM(LCM(20, 50), 75).

But how do I work on the element of the vector? Do I need loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` to keep running `lcm` with each new value in the vector

```
lcm_vector <- function(x) Reduce(lcm, x)
lcm_vector(c(20,50,75))
# [1] 300
```

If you have a vector like `x<-c(a,b,c,d,e)` and you have function `f`. Calling `Reduce(f, x)` is like calling `f(f(f(f(a, b), c), d), e)`