# Convert any decimals in each column to integers

Tags: r, vector

I have a dataset where each column might have some decimals which i wish to convert to integers.

```
structure(list(var1 = c(0.25, 1, 2), var2 = c(1, 2, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")

  var1 var2
1 0.25  1.0
2 1.00  2.0
3 2.00  0.5
```

I can multiply each column by a number to make them integers. Such as multiply first column by 4 and second by 2

```
structure(list(var1 = c(1, 4, 8), var2 = c(2, 4, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
  var1 var2
1    1    2
2    4    4
3    8    1
```

I want to do this multiplication using code.

Comment: This will not always work since multiplication of floating point numbers can produce unexpected results. See Frequently Asked Questions [7.31 Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Comment: Here is the code: `library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(var1 = var1*4,
         var2 = var2*2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generalization, suppose that your numbers are can be expressed as pretty fractions, and using @MrFlick's [lcm function for vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62681308/create-a-function-for-least-common-multiple-for-a-vector-in-r-with-helper-functi)

```
library(pracma)
library(MASS)
library(stringr)
lcm_vector <- function(x) Reduce(Lcm, x)

for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  x <- df[,i]
  x <- fractions(x[!(x %in% x[!x%%1])])
  y <- str_split(attr(x,"fracs"),"/", simplify = T)[,2]
  z <- lcm_vector(as.numeric(y))
  df[,i] <- z * df[,i]
}
df

  var1 var2
1    1    2
2    4    4
3    8    1
```

For another `df`,

```
df <- rbind(df, c(1/3, .75))
df
       var1 var2
1 0.2500000 1.00
2 1.0000000 2.00
3 2.0000000 0.50
4 0.3333333 0.75
```

applying code above will gives

```
  var1 var2
1    3    4
2   12    8
3   24    2
4    4    3
```